# Set defaultCursor in fabric.js more than once

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cursor, fabricjs

I can set `canvas.defaultCursor`, but I can't change it to something else once it's already set. Is this possible?

Here's my code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

function setCursor(cursorType) {
    if (cursorType == 'move') {
        canvas.defaultCursor = 'move';
    } else if (cursorType == 'crosshair') {
        console.log('Changing cursor to crosshair'); // this works
        canvas.defaultCursor = 'crosshair'; // this doesn't work
    }
}

setCursor('move'); // this works

// ...

setCursor('crosshair');
```

Comment: Try forcing the point across to fabric with `canvas.lowerCanvasEl.style.cursor = "crosshair"` if nothing happens then trace into fabric with dev tools and find out why `setCursor` is not doing the right thing. Many people use libraries like this but never go past the calls, its just plain old JS and tracing into the library will improve understanding and help find solutions to problems like this.

Comment: to me it just works. can you make a fiddle where it actually does not work? if i copy paste this code in kitchensink it just works fine. http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/  execute tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my sample code was incomplete.

In the full code, I was changing the cursor when the user moved the mouse near an existing canvas object, and then changing it back to the default when the mouse moved away.

Here's the missing piece: when the user hovers over an object, Fabric uses `hoverCursor` instead of `defaultCursor`. In my case, `hoverCursor` was the same as `defaultCursor`. So my code did indeed change `defaultCursor` when it was supposed to, but the user still saw the original cursor (from `hoverCursor`) when moving the mouse near the object.

I was able to solve this by changing `hoverCursor` on the object in question.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any problem with that changing.
Look the cursor in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/v1nmtz02/4/

or try the snippet here:

```js
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
function changeCursor(cursorType) {
   canvas.defaultCursor = cursorType;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeCursor('crosshair');">crosshair</button>
<button onclick="changeCursor('move');">move</button>
<button onclick="changeCursor('default');">default</button>
<canvas id='canvas' width="550" height="550" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

Comment: You're correct. See the answer that I posted. Thanks for taking the time, sorry to bug you, and thanks for the great library!

Comment: This seems to be broken.